# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Is there a data limit size)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Can't seem to figure this one out. This is my jQuery:

```
$('#submit').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/signup/createuser/',
        data:{
            email:$('#email').val(),
            password:$('#password').val(),
            terms_checkbox:$('#terms_checkbox').is(':checked'),   
            recieve_email_checkbox:$('#recieve_email_checkbox').is(':checked'),          
            phone_number:$('#phone_number'),   
            // full_name:$('#full_name'),   
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log('here');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my html:

```
<input id="full_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" value="">
<input id="phone_number" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="+1(444)444-44444" value="">
```

If I comment out phone_number - everything works fine. But when I add it - it breaks? This makes me wonder if there is a data limit on POST?

Comment: Where's the rest of the HTML? We need the other inputs to see if anything is wrong with them.

Comment: Would you please show us what do you have in $('#phone_number'). is it just a simple tag? when you have this kind of error it means you may have loop inside your code

Comment: I added to phone_number html - sorry I don't know how I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for `$('#phone_number').val()` instead of `$('#phone_number')`. jQuery will try to serialise the data for you, and it probably fails on the circular references in the jQuery collection object.